# How to integrate cortana in Universal App?

Tags: windows, cortana

I am trying to develop windows 10 app using existing website.

Here is I have followed link http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm

I am able to view my website in Windows 10 app, but I don't know how can I integrate Cortana into my web page?

I have checked this link also [WebApp: Cortana loads app, but how can I deep link into the web app with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912247/webapp-cortana-loads-app-but-how-can-i-deep-link-into-the-web-app-with-javascr)

but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this. Based on this link [WebApp: Cortana loads app, but how can I deep link into the web app with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912247/webapp-cortana-loads-app-but-how-can-i-deep-link-into-the-web-app-with-javascr) I did write code in my application

The reason cortana was not working because I need to first run windows universal application manually, so it will download vcd file from home page of website.

After running application manually first time and second time I did try to give command to cortana to open my application, it works !!!